# Excel sql db query with case statement

Tags: sql, excel, case

I am new to sql, especially when adding it into a query in Excel. I have three columns in a table (firstname,lastname, field2). Field2 contains yes/no values. I want in excel the query to pull from the table only the firstname and lastname columns, and if that field2 value contains a no, add text to say no after the last name.

select
firstname,
case field2
when ''No'' then lastname**wanting to add text here to follow last name. ex smith/No**
when  ''Yes'' then lastname
end LastName
from table1

I do get an error that the syntax cant be graphically displayed due to an error in excel which is to expect since I know my statement isnt correct. I just dont know what would be the correct way to set this up. Maybe its my tics around yes/no? or do I have the case/when words in the wrong places?

Comment: What database is used? Add appropriate tag.

Comment: SQL is a language implemented by different DBMS's that varies in their dialects of SQL. Please identify the database you are trying to use in Excel. Actually, show Excel code. VBA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use IIf(), not CASE. Consider:

If field2 is a Yes/No data type
`SELECT firstname, lastname & IIf(field2, "", "/No") AS LN FROM table1;`

If field2 is text type
`SELECT firstname, lastname & IIf(field2="yes", "", "/No") AS LN FROM table1;`